# hiding and showing dropdowns using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in a very confused state how to write this code. Actually my requirement is .. I have a 5 drop down boxes in which first one should be constant and others should remain hidden. Based on the option selected in the first drop down box i need to display other drop downs. But here comes the tricky part...
If for example.. i have selected "java" option in main drop down box java drop down box should appear , if again i select another option along with java box another drop down box should also appear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><body>
<select name="select"  value="select" id="skill" onchange="check(this[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="select"><b>select<b>
<option id="vjava" value="java"><b>java<b>
<option value="dotnet"><b>dotnet<b>
<option value="oracle"><b>oracle<b>
<option value="MSBI"><b>msbi<b>
<option value="powerbuilder"><b>powerbuilder<b>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<span id="javan"><b>java<b></span><select id="java">
<option value="beginner"><b>Beginner<b>
<option value="intermediate"><b>Intermediate<b>
<option value="expert"><b>Expert<b>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<span id="dotnetn"><b>.Net<b></span><select id="dotnet">
<option value="beginner"><b>Beginner<b>
<option value="intermediate"><b>Intermediate<b>
<option value="expert"><b>Expert<b>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<span id="oraclen">Oracle</span><select id="oracle">
<option value="beginner">Beginner
<option value="intermediate">Intermediate
<option value="expert">Expert
</select>
<br>
<br>
<span id="msbin">Msbi</span><select id="msbi">
<option value="beginner"><b>Beginner
<option value="intermediate"><b>Intermediate<b>
<option value="expert"><b>Expert<b>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<span id="powerbuildern"><b>Powerbuilder<b></span><select id="powerbuilder">
<option value="beginner"><b>Beginner<b>
<option value="intermediate"><b>Intermediate<b>
<option value="expert"><b>Expert<b>
</select>
</body></html>
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have a multi-select dropdown? And please post the code you have.

Comment: `<option>` elements can't contain anything other than a simple string, no child elements (the nested `<b>` is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using Jquery

```js
$("#main").on("change", function() {
  if ($("#main").val() == "Java") {
    $("#Java").removeClass("h");
    $("#Java").addClass("s");
  }

  if ($("#main").val() == ".net") {
    $("#Net").removeClass("h");
    $("#Net").addClass("s");
  }

  if ($("#main").val() == "C#") {
    $("#C").removeClass("h");
    $("#C").addClass("s");
  }

})
```

```css
.h {
  display: none;
}
.s {
  dsplay: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="main">
  <option>Java
    <option>
      <option>.net
        <option>
          <option>C#
            <option>
</select>

<select id="Java" class="h">
  <option>Java</option>
</select>


<select id="Net" class="h">
  <option>.Net</option>
</select>


<select id="C" class="h">
  <option>C#</option>
</select>
```

Let me know if that what u are asking

Comment: Thanks! But one thing i needed is if i select three boxes i want the main select box to come below all of them.